# CodeIgniter allways unable load file as header in the page

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, fileloadexception

I have a problem when try to code something with CodeIgniter.
Always appear in the title of the tab "Error", and in the body of the page appear:

> ```
>  <h1>Error</h1>
>     unable to load the requested file:
> ```
>
> Then appear all the things I had programed correctly.
>
> ```
>     .php
> ```

And this is the structure of all my pages... The controllers works OK, the models works OK, and the views are as I want... except this error...

So I think I change something in the configuration or other place... but I cannot find the mistake...

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, i had all of this. The way to load a view is:

`private $defaultTemplate = 'bills/index';`
`$this->load->view($this->defaultTemplate,NULL);`

The views is correcty loading, but I have allway this:
`<html lang="en">`
`<head>`
`<meta charset="utf-8">`
`<title>Error</title>`
`<style type="text/css">`
`<head>`
`  <script src="localhost/intion/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>`
`  <script src="localhost/intion/assets/js/jqueryui.js"></script>`
`  <style type="text/css">`

BLA BLA BLA

`</p>**.php**</p> </div>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

Comment: try changing the `private $defaultTemplate = 'bills/index';` to `public $defaultTemplate = 'bills/index';` maybe the acccess to the variable will be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Could be a path error. Look carefully and check that you are using this pattern

```
$this->load->view('path'); // please note the " ' " that I used.
```

And this if you want to pass parameters to your view:

```
 $data['something']=$something;
 $this->load->view('content', $data);
```

I'm pretty sure you're not passing your data correctly to the view.

Yo have to consider that default root path of view function is application/view, so construct the path consistently.

If that does not work a bit of your coding may be useful.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, i had all of this. The way to load a view is: private $defaultTemplate = 'bills/index'; $this->load->view($this->defaultTemplate,NULL); The views is correcty loading, but I have allway this: <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Error</title> <style type="text/css"> <head> ` <script src="localhost/intion/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` ` <script src="localhost/intion/assets/js/jqueryui.js"></script>` ` <style type="text/css">` BLA BLA BLA </p>**.php**</p> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: Try by adding the html extension when loading the view:  `$defaultTemplate = 'bills/index.html';  $this->load->view($defaultTemplate,null);`